# Rails composite group count fails for long aliases. How can I fix this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We are trying to count messages in a conversation and group by user_id and conversation_id. It seems like the conversation_id+user_id column alias is truncating after 64 characters. What do I need to change in my code to avoid this truncation and help rails properly parse the result set. Since the column name is truncated, rails ignores that column and does not generate the proper result set.

Here's my code:

```
replies = EmailMessage.joins(:email_conversation)
      .where(<irrelevant selectors>)
      .group('email_conversations.user_id, email_messages.email_conversation_id').count
```

And I get a result set like so:

> {39092=>1, 43553=>1, 43555=>3,...}

but I expected a result set like this:

> {[39092, 1234]=>1, [43553, 1235]=>1, [43555, 1236]=>3,...}

Here's the query that AR generates from the initial code snippet:

> SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, email_conversations.user_id,
>   email_messages.email_conversation_id AS
>   email_conversations_user_id_email_messages_email_conversation_i FROM
>   "email_messages" INNER JOIN "email_conversations" ON
>   "email_conversations"."id" = "email_messages"."email_conversation_id"
>   WHERE "email_messages"."sender_type" = $1 AND
>   "email_conversations"."email_domain_id" IN (SELECT
>   "email_domains"."id" FROM "email_domains" WHERE
>   "email_domains"."tenant_id" = $2) AND ("email_messages"."created_at"
>   BETWEEN $3 AND $4) GROUP BY email_conversations.user_id,
>   email_messages.email_conversation_id

I believe that the count alias "**email_conversations_user_id_email_messages_email_conversation_i**" should be "**email_conversations_user_id_email_messages_email_conversation_id**"

When I run the query, I get the following result set:
[image]

The data looks good, but I suspect that AR does not know what to do with that column name.

What do I need to do to my AR query to get the expected result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell Rails that it's grouping on two columns, by passing them as separate arguments to `group`:

```
replies = EmailMessage.joins(:email_conversation)
      .where(<irrelevant selectors>)
      .group('email_conversations.user_id', 'email_messages.email_conversation_id').count
```